Best practical way to replace/reinforce this vulnerable stormwater drain pipe
I have this section of 100mm (4 inch) PVC pipe that is about 1800mm (6 feet) long. It is in an awkward location and cannot be relocated. Unfortunately it is at the perfect height for people to stand on, and has suffered breakage at least twice.
The pipe is for storm-water/gutter runoff.

(Not shown are the two PVC pipe supports that also broke, and were removed.)
Clearly a bit of work is needed to prevent this breaking again, next time someone tries to use it as a step or seat. I figure I have three options:

Replace the pipe and add an 'excessive' number of supports, say one every 6 inches
Replace the PCV pipe with a stronger, metal alternative
Construct some kind of metal sheath/protector that covers and protects the pipe

Perhaps a combination of all three options.
Do any of you have advice on the best practical solution?
Thanks in advance

In this location people are going to stand on the pipe to look over the railing,

@Jasen Almost certainly, they will stand on it, they might sit on it. It is accessible to the public and you get all sorts of people passing by including drunks (we are near bars)

Is the pipe backpitched?  Hard to tell from the photo angle (and broken pipe).

@Huesmann when it was properly installed (i.e. prior to being broken) it was on a proper angle to fully drain. NOW, it is slightly backpitched due to the damage (the pipe is cracked and slightly "banana" shaped and this will be fixed when I replace it.

There are different wall thicknesses on pvc pipe.  You probably have a cheap thin wall pipe.  Upgrade to schedule 80 and you won't have any issues.  I'd probably use a mortar bag and fill the area between the pipe and the concrete once you have the slope established this will support it properly.

Thanks for the suggestion - In my part of the world, schedule 80 pipe seems to only be available from industrial specialists, and 'unreasonably' expensive for a short section of pipe. So, unless I can find a better local supplier I am probably priced out of this solution.

Even schedule 40 is going to be pretty rigid and hard to break - are you still priced out of that ?

Will have a look! Thanks

In this location people are going to stand on the pipe to look over the railing into the well.
I would go with a 3mm steel cover folded to fit this location and fastened with expanding bolts or similar.  draw a picture of what you need an go to a sheet metal place.
Another alternative would be to replace the pipe with stronger PVC - like schedule 80 and use metal supports, perhaps even concrete under it,
a metal pipe could work, but copper is probably too week so steel or cast iron...

silly question: how quickly will a steel pipe rust? Are they OK as stormwater pipes?

The cover made out of pressure treated lumber would do the job as well. It wouldn't rust, that's like anything else outdoors would need to be maintained.

I don't know how long a galvanised steel downpipe  will last, a lot depends on the  quality and quantity of rain you get. probably 10 years or more.

A flimsy flashing might do the job. Anchor it to the bottom of the railing, or the top of the concrete wall, so that the flashing can angle downward over the top of the pipe. Choose a steep angle, perhaps 45° or so, that communicates "this thing is steep and slippery; you really don't want to try to sit or stand here." It'll get bent when people try anyway but I think most will feel it give beneath them and re-consider before they've even borne any weight on the pipe itself.
Apart from that, place shims or other support below the pipe. The pipe wall is apparently strong enough to carry the weight of a person. A piece of dimensional lumber in contact with the bottom of the pipe, and shims between that lumber and the concrete, would provide a path to transfer force/weight from the top of the pipe to lumber to concrete and avoid pipe breakage.

OP could also put bricks below the pipe to support it, then mortar/grout them in place.
Basically run a masonry cradle under the pipe.  Wouldn't prevent it from being crushed, but would help prevent flexural breakage.

I'd consider embedding the entire pipe in concrete, raising the height of the wall it's sitting on to perhaps level with the black concrete behind it.
While this is probably not the cheapest option, its probably the most rugged. Metal or thicker plastic pipes are still going to dent or break eventually unless you go full cast-iron.

Personally I am not wild about making things that hard to maintain, but it would need maintenance much less often, so it's a valid trade-off.

@keshlam It's a stormwater pipe so maintenance is pretty minimal, especially when not exposed to damage. Putting a clean-out at the street end with the access flush with the top of the concrete could be a good option.
